# Pushing an element onto the stack using linked lists

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, stack, head

why when pushing an element onto stack do you return the head pointer? Is this necessary or just good practice? Thank you so much, i think i'm missing something. For example:

```
   struct node* push(struct node* head,int data)
   {
    struct node* tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
    exit(0);
    }
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Please also tag this as C to indicate which language is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you return `head` is so that you don't lose the head of the list.

Think of how a linked list is structured. When you have four items in the list, it looks like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

'head' is the first element, `A`.

Now, you're going to push a new item, call it `X`, onto the stack. You add it to the head of the list:

```
X -> A -> B -> C -> D
```

Now, `head` is the new first element, `X`.

Now, let's look at how you use this. You have a linked list pointer, call it `listHead`, which you initialize to `NULL`. You want to add items to it:

```
struct node* listHead = NULL;
...
listHead = push(listHead, 22);
```

If you didn't return `head` from the `push` function, then you'd never assign a new value to `listHead`. It would always be `NULL`;

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have come back to it many times <3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a stack on top of singly linked list, you have to insert new  node on `head` always. Because if you would insert node from `tail`, during popping up/removing a node, you would need to make `tail->prev` as new `tail`. But there is no `prev` pointer on singly linked list.